# Launching or running ica file with autoit script

Tags: autoit

I am trying to run a .ica file that I exported from XenApp from an autoit script, I used the run command and it did nothing. Any alternatives will be appreciated. Due to the sensitive nature of the .ica file i am unable to post the contents, but here is what i have so far for the autoit script.

```
Global $username = ""
Global $password = ""
Global $userinput
Global $passwordinput
$userinput = InputBox("HUB ID","Please Enter your HUB ID")
$passwordinput = InputBox("Password","Please Enter Your Password","","*15")

Run("Table Management 4_5 CorpFL.ica","C:\Users\username\Desktop\folderofICAfiles")
```

the ICA's function is to run an application on a citrix server, the user will only have access to that application and will not be able to log on to the server itself. if there is any way to run the ica using autoit please let me know.

Comment: got it to work, used ShellExecuteWait command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, used 
         ShellExecuteWait("file","","C:\Users\username\Desktop\folderwithica,"open")
worked perfectly