# How to open a .ica downloaded file from selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, citrix

I have a below code. after `ds.Click();` one file will be downloaded to downloads folder, the file will be as a **.ica extension**.

```
IWebDriver cobj = new ChromeDriver();

cobj.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://XX.xxx.xx");

IWebElement u = cobj.FindElement(By.Name("login"));
IWebElement p = cobj.FindElement(By.Name("passwd"));
IWebElement b = cobj.FindElement(By.Id("Log_On"));
u.SendKeys("username");
p.SendKeys("password");
b.Click();
IWebElement d = cobj.FindElement(By.Id("folderLink_0"));
d.Click();
IWebElement ds = cobj.FindElement(By.Id("idCitrix.Production"));
ds.Click();
```

How to open that file?

Comment: is there any option to set Always open this file type to the chrome driver .. Please help

Comment: I have already checked that post.. There is no class representing Chrome profile in C#

Comment: ?? What do you mean? What's *Chrome profile*?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open in it in the browser, you can use something like that:

```
cobj.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///C:/Users/yourUserName/Downloads/image004.jpg");
```

Just change the file type and so on.

Comment: Thanks Anton Angelov.. The above code works for txt files.. but couldnt open .ica file ..

Answer (score 1):

You can't open files with Selenium. Opening files is part of the operating system. Selenium only drives the browser, so after the file is downloaded Selenium is finished.

Some other tools to pick-up after Selenium has downloaded the file:

- AutoIt: [Launching or running ica file with autoit script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520426/launching-or-running-ica-file-with-autoit-script)
- Sikuli: https://hellotestworld.com/2012/04/27/sikuli-for-all-those-hard-to-reach-places/
- Coded-UI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Automating Citrix is also not possible with Selenium.

- [Can we automate Application available under Citrix Program Neighbourhood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279876/can-we-automate-application-available-under-citrix-program-neighbourhood)